# DHCP failover/DNS not working when primary server is offline

Tags: dhcp, bind, centos7

In a VMware environment we deploy daily many new virtual hosts and for this we need a failover DHCP/DNS.

Based of CentOS 7 I setup two virtual hosts as failover DHCP and dynamic DNS (dns01/dns02).
I setup a test network "VM Sandbox" and in this network the both server should work as DHCP/DNS servers.
Each of this servers has two networks interfaces:

- eno16777984 IP via company DHCP, connected to company network
- eno33557248 fix IP, connected to "VM Sandbox" 10.130.x.x, 255/255.0.0 
  (IP's: dns01 = 10.130.0.5 / dns02 = 10.130.0.6)

As long both servers are online all is working fine. Also when I stop the DHCP/DNS service on secundary server or shutdown it (I want to check the system when one of the servers are not available)
But if the primary server is offline the system is no longer fully working.

Existing hosts can still contacted via name but not new created hosts.
For new deployed virt. hosts still the old IP address is used.
('old IP used' because I shutdown down existing host, destroy it and deploy it new)

When I stop the services on primary server:

Secondary Server dns02 - /var/log/messages:

```
Nov  2 13:33:19 dns02 dhcpd: peer vlab: disconnected
Nov  2 13:33:19 dns02 dhcpd: failover peer vlab: I move from normal to communications-interrupted
```

Then shutdown virt. host "s0960057", destroy it and deploy it new

```
Nov  2 13:36:47 dns02 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:50:56:b6:fb:e6 via eno33557248
Nov  2 13:36:48 dns02 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.130.7.167 to 00:50:56:b6:fb:e6 (s0960057) via eno33557248
Nov  2 13:36:48 dns02 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.130.7.167 (10.130.0.6) from 00:50:56:b6:fb:e6 (s0960057) via eno33557248
Nov  2 13:36:48 dns02 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.130.7.167 to 00:50:56:b6:fb:e6 (s0960057) via eno33557248
Nov  2 13:37:00 dns02 named[24444]: client 10.130.0.6#23446/key ddns-update: signer "ddns-update" approved
Nov  2 13:37:00 dns02 named[24444]: client 10.130.0.6#23446/key ddns-update: forwarding update for zone 'vlab.xxx/IN'
Nov  2 13:37:00 dns02 named[24444]: zone vlab.xxx/IN: could not forward dynamic update to 10.130.0.5#53: operation canceled
Nov  2 13:37:00 dns02 dhcpd: Unable to add forward map from s0960057.vlab.xxx to 10.130.7.167: SERVFAIL
```

*ping s0960057 

PING s0960057.vlab.xxx (10.130.7.169) 56(84) bytes of data.* 

-> Still the old IP is used.

*nslookup s0960057

Server:         10.130.0.6

Address:        10.130.0.6#53



Name:   s0960057.vlab.xxx

Address: 10.130.7.169*

-> Still the old IP is used.

*ping 10.130.7.167

PING 10.130.7.167 (10.130.7.167) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 10.130.7.167: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.128 ms*

-> ping via IP is working

What can be the problem.
What additional data are needed.

Best Regards
  Werner